# bind9 SOA issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

using DNSStuff site to run checks against our bind9 DNS servers and it's coming back with

```
One or more SOA fields are outside recommended ranges. Values that are out of specifications could cause delays in record updates or unnecessary network traffic. The SOA fields out of range are:
mname | paof.com. | MNAME - we check that this name matches one of the nameservers that we have found.



@       IN      SOA     paof.com. root.paof.com. ( ...etc )
@       IN      SPF     "v=spf1 ip4:207.30.xx.xx ip4:209.16.xx.xx ip4:207.30.xx.xx ip4:207.30.xx.xx mx ~all"
@       IN      TXT     "v=spf1 ip4:207.30.xx.xx ip4:209.16.xx.xx ip4:207.30.xx.xx ip4:207.30.xx.xx mx ~all"
@       IN      NS      dns3.palremote.com.
@       IN      NS      dns4.palremote.com.
@       IN      NS      dns5.palremote.com.
@       IN      NS      dns6.palremote.com.
```

I'm not sure how to satisfy the SOA across DNS servers since the NS records are considered out of band I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a SOA record the first field is called the MNAME record. The MNAME record must be a name-server that will respond authoritatively for your domain. You have declared that to be `paof.com.`.

The problem is that at this time there is no `A` record for `paof.com.`, which makes it impossible to test if that host is actually an authoritative name-server for your domain or not.
Second `paof.com.` is also not listed as a name-server for your domain. AFAIK that is not an actual RFC requirement, but apparently DNSstuff is of the opinion is should be.

Since your primary name servers are `dns[3-6].palremote.com.` a logical value for the MNAME record would be one of those, e.g.

```
@       IN      SOA     dns3.palremote.com. root.paof.com. (
                          2014100800 ; sn = serial number
                          172800     ; ref = refresh = 2d
                          900        ; ret = update retry = 15m
                          1209600    ; ex = expiry = 2w
                          3600       ; nx = nxdomain ttl = 1h
                          )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have configured your primary name server to the value of `$ORIGIN`.

You need something like :

```
$ORIGIN paof.com.

@     IN   SOA   ns1 root [ ... ]

      IN   NS    ns1

[ ... ]

ns1   IN   A     X.X.X.X
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SOA` record has several fields, the first of which is named `MNAME`.

The `MNAME` field is supposed to identify the master nameserver.
In your case, however, the `MNAME` value does not correspond to any of the nameservers.

Ie, your set of nameservers is `dns3.palremote.com.`, `dns4.palremote.com.`, `dns5.palremote.com.`, `dns6.palremote.com.` but the `SOA` `MNAME` refers to `paof.com.` (not one of the nameservers).